# Downgrade from SSAS to PowerPivot

Tags: ssas, powerpivot

Can I downgrade from SSAS to PowerPivot in excel 2013?

Reason being - I have 64 bit excel installed on my machine but my SSDT is VS 2012 shell 32 bit.

Its really slow on VS 2012. I have no control of how software to be installed on my machine and have been passed on this laptop so I dont have much choice actually.

Can anyone please guide me how to do this?
Thak you.

Peddie

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use PowerPivot you have to install Excel. PowerPivot is an Excel add-in.

Now, SSDT only comes in a 32-bit version, there is no 64-bit version to install. Even if it were available you'd probably wouldn't see any performance improvement in your case because the data model is not actually "processed" by SSDT. You build in SSDT and then deploy to a SSAS server in tabular mode. If the model you build is slow it could be because a lot of reasons, one of them being that the SSAS server your deploying to is running on your local machine.

If you want to move your data model from SSAS to PowerPivot, try this http://blog.gbrueckl.at/2014/05/restoring-a-ssas-tabular-model-to-power-pivot/.

It involves taking a backup of your tabular model and then restore that in PowerPivot. It's worked for me in the past.